# what is the most common way to organize symbols in an algorithm?

Tags: sorting

I was on a website where companies were listed in alphabetical order, names that started with a number were ranked higher than the letter A, names that started with a symbol ($) were ranked higher than the number 0. Where can I find how symbols are alphabetized?  I asked the site owner for example if ! would come before $  and they didn't know, they said it was some off the shelf software and it was just part of the algorithm.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/  `!` seems to be the first printable character, `~` the last.  (Assuming it is ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you want to search is "lexicographic order".

Generally the symbols will be sorted by their order in the [ASCII character encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/). If you have "funny symbols" (Unicode) in your strings, like the Russian "Главное в новостях", those will be probably be sorted by their numeric code point in the Unicode tables.

This is the same way your computer's file browser orders file names, so the general rules should be familiar to you already.

---

In this particular example, the bang character `!` is ASCII `0x21` and the dollar symbol `$` is ASCII `0x24`, so the bang `!` would come first in the sorting order.

---

Sometimes some "human-friendly" sorting features are incorporated on top of this: when sorting file names, for example, my computer orders leading numbers like:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
11.txt
100.txt
```

Which is in order by numeric value, instead of the plain lexicographic sort

```
1.txt
100.txt
11.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

which doesn't quite match the way humans like to think about numeric filenames.